# POST parameters mysteriously eaten after using spring security & an ntlm filter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security, ntlm

I have a custom filter that carries out spring security authentication by checking in a database, and another that checks an NTLM provider.

The problem is this:

1. Enter URL
   http://myapp.com/app/somestuff/stuff
2. Get redirected to http://myapp.com/login.jsp
3. Enter correct login details and authenticate.
4. All forms on both
   http://myapp.com/app/somestuff/stuff
   and http://myapp.com/app/somestuff/
   don't work... the post variables
   simply don't make it to the
   server!!!

I checked that the post variables don't make it to the server by putting a filter which prints them out at the top of my web.xml.  They're all null.

This problem also has the capability of disabling the login page.  Please help, I'm really tearing my hair out over this!!!

Comment: How do you filter perform redirect after successful login? Does it use `SavedRequest` (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/SavedRequest.html)?

Comment: If your `POST` variables don't make it to the server, it's likely they are not even being sent by the browser...