# Spring security Custom Filter: cannot read FROM POST parameter

Tags: spring-security, servlet-filters, servlets, form-post

I am trying to read a form-post parameter with the following code:

```
String hohumId = request.getParameter("HOHUM_ID");

if (hohumId == null) {
throw new
    PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("ID not found in request");
}
```

This is inside a Spring-Security Custom Filter, the result is always null. I have used Tamper Data in FireFox and the form parameter is in the 'Post Parameter List'.

It is as though the form data is being mysteriously stripped away. My question is very similar to the following question. Couldn't find a solution though.

[POST parameters mysteriously eaten after using spring security & an ntlm filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824932/post-parameters-mysteriously-eaten-after-using-spring-security-an-ntlm-filter)

Comment: Which filter are you extending and at which position in the chain are you running it ?

Comment: i'm extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter my security.xml looks like: <custom-filter ref="pubCookiePreAuthFilter"  position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>

Comment: Have you used a debugger to verify that the parameters (ALL parameters) are in fact gone? This should be easy to verify and would provide more clarity as to what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: i'm using Eclipse Helios SR 2 + Tomcat 7.0.14 (running T/C within eclipse). The break point reveals the following: HttpServletRequest is actually org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper, wonder if this 'wrapping' is inadvertently pruning the post data. The parameterMap is also null and there are no POST variables. By the way, I'm reading your book, thank you. Helped me a lot understanding Spring Security.